# Send Email with all new OneNote entries

Tags: onenote

I use Microsoft OneNote daily to take notes.  I would like to write a script to send myself an email every night with all the new notes I took that day across notebooks so I can review them.  This would usually be straightforward in e.g. a Word doc where I can timestamp all saves and take the latest file, diff it with the last file from the previous day and send the diff.  Unfortunately OneNote complicates this for at least two reasons:

1. OneNote autosaves and as far as I can tell does not offer the ability to rename saves or add a timestamp to the filename
2. Notebooks and pages mean changes are across "documents" instead of a single file that can be diff'd.

So I am looking for a solution that considers the complications above.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you using onedrive personal or SharePoint?

Comment: I am not using any SharePoints that I am aware of

Comment: I do something similar, except... (a) I do this once a week rather than once a day, (b) I use the OneTastic macros for OneNote to find the pages modified, (c) I have to manually kick it off (and wait a long time) - I have not figured out how to run OneTastic macros in the background, cron-style.  // NOTE: I use local OneNote as well as two different cloud storage - work and personal - so AFAIK the microsoft-graph API does not work for the local pages. // ALSO, AFAIK no automated diff - have to do that manually.

Answer (score 1):

The basic approach via the microsoft-graph API

```
./me/onenote/pages?$filter=lastModifiedDateTime ge yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ&$expand=parentNotebook
```

will yield json data with
**title** - Page title
**links/oneNoteWebUrl** - allows opening of the onenote page in web browser
**links/oneNoteClientUrl** - allows opening of the onenote page in onenote app
**parentNotebook/displayName** - Notebook name
**self** - needed to get page content.

for small page numbers this may work but is likely to time out with a 504 error for a drive with many pages.
In that case a two stage approach is required.

```
./me/onenote/sections?$filter=lastModifiedDateTime ge yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ
```

will return a list of all the sections that have been modified since the defined lastModifiedDateTime.
Next iterate through the returned json data and get pages modified since lastModifiedDateTime with the returned pagesUrls using the format

```
.me/onenote/sections/1-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/pages?$filter=lastModifiedDateTime ge yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ&$expand=parentNotebook
```

yielding the same data as noted previously.
Once you have this data you can generate an email containing a list of the modified Notebooks,page names and page links.
If you need the actual page data(content) then you need to call

```
./me/onenote/pages/1-1c13bcbae2fdd747a95b3e5386caddf1!1-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/content?includeIDs=true&includeInkML=true&preAuthenticated=true
```

Which will give you text/html, ink and links to other resources from each page.

Comment: Thanks--Do I need an account with Microsoft to use the Graph API?  I want to use your solution in my work environment but I am not sure I am able to set up an account.