# Auto-Convert OneNote to PDF

Tags: onenote

I am trying to automatically convert some Microsoft OneNote files to PDF to send as a daily email attachment.  I have thought of two systematic solutions but need some help in finding the right tools:

1. Find an application that may be programmatically called (via a Python script e.g.) that will convert a Microsoft OneNote file to a PDF.
2. Find a way for OneNote to automatically save files as PDFs every time it auto-saves.

Is anyone aware of tools available for either solution?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52317456/send-email-with-all-new-onenote-entries#comment91697096_52317456)
The approach would be to get the pages content with

```
./me/onenote/pages/1-1c13bcbae2fdd747a95b3e5386caddf1!1-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/content?includeIDs=true&includeInkML=true&preAuthenticated=true
```

and then render the html on a canvas with javascript/jquery.
render ink with [InkMLjs](https://github.com/Microsoft/InkMLjs)
and then use a library to convert the canvas to a pdf for example with [canvas2pdf](https://github.com/joshua-gould/canvas2pdf)
Another approach might be something like Automator for osx. You could get the pages of interest with the microsoft-graph api, open them in a web browser using applescript and when the page has finished rendering -> print -> "Save as PDF"